# Facebook pages question

Tags: facebook, fbml

I have a few questions that I hope some can help with, I am creating a facebook page for a business and they are wanting to display a list of products, that are pulled directly from there own website, is it possible to pull an XML feed from the website, then display the data using FBML?  Secondly is it possible to only show certain content if the user has 'liked the page'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do this with a script on your server. E.g. a PHP-script which fetches the XML and outputs FBML.

Answer (score 0):

FBML has been deprecated so building something with it is risky. It might stop working suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

For showing content only to users that liked you fan page you can use following:

```
 <fb:visible-to-connection>
    Content for fans goes here
  <fb:else>
    You are not a fan, you do not have access to this content
  </fb:else>
 </fb:visible-to-connection>
```

For XML displaying of product you will have to build a facebook application that will run in fan tab tab.